# How can I find the number of views all MATLAB questions have received?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I want to calculate the total number of question views that a tag on Stack Overflow has. Let's say the tag is MATLAB. At present there are 88k questions asked on Stack Overflow with tagged [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab). Now each of these questions has some views.

Is there a way for me to know the total question views that these 88k questions have together via Stack Exchange API?

Comment: Can you outline the code you are using at the moment, and what problem you are having with it? What language are you using?

Comment: I am looking to find how to calculate the total number of question views that a tag on stack overflow has.
Lets say the tag is MATLAB. 
At present there are 88k questions asked on Stack overflow with tag = MATLAB.
Is there a way for me to calculate the total question views that these 88k questions have together via Stack exchange api

Comment: My other question is similar where I want to find the total number of votes that all 88k questions have in together. 
For finding the total questions, i am using the below api 
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?todate=1593993600&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=matlab&site=stackoverflow&filter=total

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few [matlab](/questions/tagged/matlab) questions and given that the API returns a maximum of 100 results per page and it has a limit of 10k calls per day (when you use a key), I wouldn't suggest using it in this case.

Instead, use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com). Here is an example SQL query which should satisfy your rrequirement:

```sql
DECLARE @from_date AS date = '##FromDate##'
DECLARE @to_date AS date = '##ToDate##'

SELECT SUM(CAST(ViewCount AS BIGINT)) AS view_count FROM Posts
WHERE PostTypeId = 1
  AND CreationDate > @from_date
  AND CreationDate < @to_date
  AND Tags LIKE '%##Tag##%'
```

This will sum the the `ViewCount` columnn's values, which are the number of views each question has. Since you want only questions, you need to have `PostTypeId` set to `1`.

Note that this finds the *total* views of questions tagged [tag](/questions/tagged/tag). It's impossible to know the views a question has received up to a certain date.

[Here is the query live](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1260781). Enter a tag name in the Tag input and Run Query! If the tag has many questions, then the query might time out.

See also: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678) on Meta Stack Exchange.